# Will my administrator see what I did when I deleted my history after my computer became blocked?

Tags: network, privacy

I was on my work computer and clicked on one website, then it shows it's blocked. I've deleted history; will my employer/network admin see what I did?

Comment: No problem. The site has a few different parts to get to know.

Answer (score 5):

**Relax, it happens all the time.**

Yes, it will likely be logged in the proxy performing the blocking, but unless you are doing it over and over and over, dozens of times, it's unlikely to rise to the level of anyone caring about you personally.

If the block site is showing up many times for many employees, it may generate some interest as to the vector that's effecting so many people.

Answer (score 1):

> I was on my work computer and clicked on one website , then it shows its blocked. Ive deleted history will my employer/network admin see what i did ?

The information could have been logged and your employer could be able to see the information, even if you deleted your browsing history. E.g., an endpoint firewall or AV program could log that information independently of your browser.

Whether or not they really *can* or *will*  see it (and with what probability) depends on a lot of other factors.

Seems like, given all the other major problems IT/security staff have to deal with, they would likely not be too concerned with one website click.